# How to get the a child's parent's ID in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I need to get the child's parent's ID

Heres what I Mean:

```html
<div class="task" id="TheParent">
    <img class="task-img" src="./index.png" />
    <div class="Text-Container">
        <p class="task-maintitle">Sample Task</p>
        <p class="task-desc">Sample Desc</p>
    </div>
 
    <input type="checkbox" class="Check" id="check" onclick="Remove(this.id)" />
              <!--Need this element's parent's id-->  
</div>
```

> I need to get it with `this` specifically because there are going to be many elements which are just duplicates.

Is there any way to get the parent's id?

Comment: `this.parentElement.id`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get it with [`this.parentNode`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_node_parentnode.asp)

*I added `this.parentNode.id` for the demo purpose*

```js
function getParent(parenId) {
   console.log(parenId)
}
```

```html
<div id="parent-div">
   <button onclick="getParent(this.parentNode.id)">
     Test
   </button>
</div>
```